# Edge detection of histogram - python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically I have some data that I have made a histogram from. No great difficulty there, just use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist(data,bins=num)`
However, I want to do a kind-of Sobel edge detection where basically the `ith` histogram bar/bin (whatever the jargon is) becomes `-2*(i-1)th+0*(i)th+2*(i+1)th`
I have worked out/found out that you can do (my data is in columnated txt files)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alldata = np.genfromtxt('filename', delimiter=' ')
data = alldata[:,18]
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(data,bins=30)
```

Which returns/gives

```
>>> n
array([3,0,3,3,6,1,...etc])

>>> bins 
array([13.755,14.0298,14.3046,... etc])

>>> patches
<a list of 30 Patch objects>
```

Here I can perform my operation on `n` to get my sobel-filtered stuff, (Side note: I just do this iteratively over the array, is there an easier way with something like `a = [-2,0,2]`?)

## So, my question and problem!  **I have no idea how to then reconstruct the result as a histogram or line-plot ...** AND keep the same horizontal axis `bins`

---

UPDATE

---

Here is the code that I use to get this far. Download the data [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59920113/S_MOS152_cut.txt)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ignore this, it is so it makes it easier to iterate over later.
filNM = 'S_MOS152_cut'
filID = filNM + '.txt'
nbins = 30

# extract the data from file
stars = np.genfromtxt(filID, delimiter=' ')
imag = stars[:,18]

# let's start the histogram dance
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(imag, bins=nbins)

# now apply the edge filter (manually for lack of a better way)
nnew=[0 for j in xrange(nbins)]

for i in range(0,len(n)):
if i==0:
    nnew[i]=2*n[i+1]
elif i==len(n)-1:
    nnew[i]=-2*n[i-1]
else:
    nnew=-2*n[i-1]+2*n[i+1]

np.array(nnew)
# I do this because it now generates the same form 
# output as if you just say >>> print plt.hist(imag, bins=nbins)
filt = nnew,bins,patches 
print filt
```

## Now I have nowhere to go, if I try to plot `filt` it gives me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say, make a histogram with `np.histogaram`, apply Sobel filter and then `plt.hist` it.

```
>>> n, bins=histogram(q, bins=30)
>>> bin_updated=[item for item, jtem in zip(bins, n) if do_Sobel_stuff_on(jtem)]
>>> plt.hist(data, bins=bin_updated)
```

OK, basically, you want to use `.set_height()` method:

```
>>> a=range(1000)
>>> n,b,p=plt.hist(a)
>>> p[0]
<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x026E1070>
>>> p[0].get_height()
100
>>> p[0].set_height(19)
>>> plt.show()
>>> n_adjusted #your new n
>>> for i1, i2 in zip(p, n_adjusted):
        i1.set_height(i2)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not the bin size that I need to operate on but the `n` essentially it modifies the height of the histogram bars....

Comment: Awesome, looks promising. I will have a mess around with that in a bit and get back to you! On second thought, it should work exactly!

Comment: Definitely does the job! Do you have a way to make it a line-plot? Cheers CT Zhu

Comment: This does the job, but only visually; for those who use it in the future. It does not alter the actual data just the rectangle heights.